# Usar las propiedades de una lista anidada en un hashmap para guardar resultados

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Estoy intentando guardar los datos de un formulario dinámico en un mapa cuyo valor es una lista de objetos, el problema está en que cuando llego al método `POST` correspondiente, en el mapa, las `entryKey` están todas bien con sus objetos correspondientes pero cuando miro el valor `table` del mapa las que deberían estar rellenas aparecen como `null`.

El mapa es el siguiente, lo inicializo antes de procesar los datos:

```
private Map<String, List<FilterForm>> filtros = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<FilterForm>>();

public CustomSearchForm() {
        this.filtros.put("datos_personales", new ArrayList<FilterForm>());
        this.filtros.put("datos_institucion", new ArrayList<FilterForm>());

}
```

Antes de recger los datos seteo las listas con todos los campos.

```
public void setDefaultFilters(SearchService ss) {
        SearchType type = (SearchType) ss.findTypeById(searchType);
        this.searchTypeName = type.getName();
        FilterForm filterForm = null;
        SearchTable table = (SearchTable) ss.findTableByAlias(searchTable, searchType);
        List<FilterForm> filters = new ArrayList<FilterForm>();
        for (SearchField field : table.getFields()) {
            filterForm = new FilterForm(field.getName(), field.getAlias(), field.getF_type().getName());
            filters.add(filterForm);
        }
        if (searchTypeName.equals(Constantes.SEARCH_TYPE_PERSONAS)) {
            switch (searchTable) {
            case "Datos personales":
                this.filtros.get("datos_personales").addAll(filters);
                break;
            case "Formas de contacto":
                this.filtros.get("p_formas_contacto").addAll(filters);
                break;
            case "Instituciones":
                this.filtros.get("p_instituciones").addAll(filters);
                break;
            case "Relaciones":
                this.filtros.get("p_relaciones").addAll(filters);
                break;
            case "Patronos":
                this.filtros.get("p_patronos").addAll(filters);
                break;
            case "Candidatura":
                this.filtros.get("p_candidatura").addAll(filters);
                break;
            }
        } else if (searchTypeName.equals(Constantes.SEARCH_TYPE_INSTITUCIONES)) {
            switch (searchTable) {
            case "Datos de la institución":
                this.filtros.get("datos_institucion").addAll(filters);
                break;
            case "Candidatura":
                this.filtros.get("i_candidatura").addAll(filters);
                break;
            case "Formas de contacto":
                this.filtros.get("i_formas_contacto").addAll(filters);
                break;
            case "Patronos":
                this.filtros.get("i_patronos").addAll(filters);
                break;
            case "Empleados":
                this.filtros.get("i_empleados").addAll(filters);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Y recojo los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
    <select th:id="'accion_'+${f.key}+'_'+${status.index}" onchange="cambioCombo(this);" th:if="${ff.tipoCampo != 'Booleano'}" class="form-control select2me" form="customSearch"
        placeholder="Acción"
        th:field="*{filtros[__${f.key}__][__${status.index}__].accion}">
        <option th:each="a : ${customSearch.ACCIONES}" th:value="${a}"
                th:text="${a}"></option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
    <input th:id="'valueField_'+${f.key}+'_'+${status.index}" th:if="${ff.tipoCampo == 'Numero' or ff.tipoCampo == 'Texto' or ff.tipoCampo == 'Tabla'}" form="customSearch"
        type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Valor"
        th:field="*{filtros[__${f.key}__][__${status.index}__].value}" />

  <div th:if="${ff.tipoCampo == 'Fecha'}" th:id="'dateField_'+${f.key}+'_'+${status.index}" class="date"
        data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
        <input form="searchForm"
            class="form-control input-lg date" th:id="'valueFieldDate_'+${f.key}+'_'+${status.index}"
            th:field="*{filtros[__${f.key}__][__${status.index}__].value}" 
            th:name="'valueField_'+${f.key}+'_'+${status.index}" type="text" placeholder="Fecha" />
    </div>
```

La variable `f` sale de iterar el hashmap correspondiente y la variable `status` de iterar la lista dentro de dicho mapa.

Comment: ¿Utilizas algún framework como Spring MVC u otro para mapear los campos o cómo lo haces?

Comment: si, utilizo Spring MVC, los campos están dentro de un form al que en el modelo lo he llamado `customSearch` el acceso al mapa sería `customSearch.filtros[keyMap]`

Comment: El problema puede ser que instancias siempre la lista cuando se llama al método public y eso puede hacer que no se seteen los campos de la lista, porque al momento del set la lista no existe.

Comment: He editado la pregunta, antes de poder hacer la busqueda cargo las listas anidadas con valores donde los únicos campos a null son `value` y `accion` (el cual es que rellenara el usuario)

Comment: No entiendo la sección de código que has puesto, ¿puedes añadir el código de la clase completa y ademas el de las clases SearchService, SearchType, FilterForm, SearchTable y SearchField?